# how to use regex in mysql UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one is a table of parameters that the other table can have, and they're stored like this:

**Table 1**

```
id         name
1          var1
2          var2
3          var3
```

**Table 2**

```
id         name       parameters
1          name1      var1|var3
2          name2      var2
3          name3      var1|var2|var3
```

Now, when I run a DELETE query, I want to update table 2 parameters aswell, so let's say I run a DELETE query on table 1, row 1, I want to get the following table 2 result, should I query for it:

**Table 2**

```
id         name       parameters
1          name1      var3
2          name2      var2
3          name3      var2|var3
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: paramaters should be seperately saved in a third table with `t1_id` as FK for t1, `t2_id` as FK for t2 and `parameter`.

Comment: I agree with _cularis_.  You should store parameters in table 2 one per line.  If your name3 has 3 parameters, then there should be 3 rows in table 2 for it.  With this arrangement, you can declare the foreign key on table 2 with "on delete cascade" - and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restructure your tables. Normalized data modelling would tell you to use an n-to-m table structure ([many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) or [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)). So create a third table which has all references to both of your tables and resides in between your current two tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet solidified this code, I highly advise that you rework the schema before it becomes too difficult to manage.

The proper way to handle this situation in `Table 2` is not to delimit the values which key to `Table 1`, but rather to store multiple rows per `id`.  Then when deleting from `Table 1`, a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can enforce `ON DELETE CASCADE` and this becomes a non-issue.

Example Table 2 data would look like:

```
id         name
1          name1
1          name1
2          name2
3          name3
3          name3
3          name3
```

The definition of `Table 2` would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR() NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_id (id) REFERENCES Table_1 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

imho you have a small DB design problem here.  You must normalize the table 2 by doing:

id pk
name UK
parameter UK

parameter should have 1 value.  So your row no 3 should be splitted in two rows:

```
3 name3 var2
4 name3 var3
```

Or if it is too complicated, do like cularis said, add a third table.